# how does the custom skins for c# 2010 work?

Tags: c#, winforms, skins

I'm still working on my c# application in changing the GUI and after googling around i found out that there are skins that can be used. I still don't understand how does this work, do i have to start from scratch? or will the skins merge along with my c# application. what changes will the skin do in my c# application aside from the GUI?

Comment: What kind of skins are you talking about? Is this some specific skinning library? I haven't heard of using skins in WinForms before, so I suspect this isn't a standard thing...

Comment: im currently reading about it heres the link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61485/Winforms-SkinFramework

Comment: Right, well that's a specific project for using skins in Windows Forms - and a project which isn't being maintained any more. Are you sure you want to use it?

Comment: I've tried out a different skin but it covered up all of the items inside the form edit but when i run it the items are revealed back

Comment: You could try using the commercial skinning tools & libraries of [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/winforms/visual-style-builder) for WinForms. Or make the GUI of your app in WPF, if possible?

Comment: im downloading it now. luckily there's a free trial i'm only doing this for project purposes thanks.

Comment: Or use DevExpress's library.

Answer (score 1):

What i normally do for skinning is to remove form borders and set a background image,thus you can create forms of any shape.The steps i follow

```
Set the FormBorderStyle property to None.
Set the BackgroundImage property of the form to the .bmp you created above.
Set the TransparencyKey property of the form to the background color of the .bmp file
```

[image]

There are 2 parts to a winform client area and Non Client Area,You can do anything with the Client Area easily but None Client Area is uneditable.The Skinlibary you have mentioned in your comment hookes into windows message Loop to capture Events.
Check this answer to see how the Title bar color is changed [Changing the color of the title bar in WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862315/changing-the-color-of-the-title-bar-in-winform)