# How do I make my Form title bar follow the windows dark theme?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, themes

I have downloaded the **Windows 10** update that includes the **dark theme.**

File explorer et al are in dark theme, but when I create my own C# form application, the title bar is bright white.

How can I make my own desktop apps follow the dark theme that I have set in Windows?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I believe that Windows 10's dark theme only affects UWP applications. If you're using WinForms, you'll probably have to [do it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11862315/4934172).

Comment: Alternatively, you / your users may use [this option](https://i.postimg.cc/mkdxd3bw/Annotation-2019-05-26-113123.png) in Windows 10 settings which allows the selected color to apply to the title bars of all applications.

Comment: Thanks! Additionally I decided to make the border hide-able with a tickbox (show to resize and move, hide to use):

private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable == this.FormBorderStyle) this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            else this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
 }

Answer (score 4):

You need to invoke `DwmSetWindowAttribute()` from `dwmapi.dll`.

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern void DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, 
                                                DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE attribute, 
                                                ref int pvAttribute, 
                                                uint cbAttribute);
```

And also `DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE`

```
public enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE : uint
{
    DWMWA_NCRENDERING_ENABLED,
    DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY,
    DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED,
    DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT,
    DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS,
    DWMWA_NONCLIENT_RTL_LAYOUT,
    DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION,
    DWMWA_FLIP3D_POLICY,
    DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS,
    DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP,
    DWMWA_DISALLOW_PEEK,
    DWMWA_EXCLUDED_FROM_PEEK,
    DWMWA_CLOAK,
    DWMWA_CLOAKED,
    DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION,
    DWMWA_PASSIVE_UPDATE_MODE,
    DWMWA_USE_HOSTBACKDROPBRUSH,
    DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE = 20,
    DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE = 33,
    DWMWA_BORDER_COLOR,
    DWMWA_CAPTION_COLOR,
    DWMWA_TEXT_COLOR,
    DWMWA_VISIBLE_FRAME_BORDER_THICKNESS,
    DWMWA_SYSTEMBACKDROP_TYPE,
    DWMWA_LAST
}
```

When your form initializes

```
var preference = Convert.ToInt32(true);
DwmSetWindowAttribute(this.Handle, 
                      DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE, 
                      ref preference, sizeof(uint));
```

and the title bar of your form will be dark.

Here's Screenshot.
Sorry for the mica transparency of windows 11.

[image]

Comment: How do you obtain the right `Handle`?

Comment: This handle is the handle of your form. Or you can write `this.Handle`

Comment: `Handle` comes automatically from the `Control` and the `Form` also inherits `Control`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I updated your answer (this.Handle).

Comment: I tried it with this modification - it compiles and runs, but doesn't create a dark color in the title.

Comment: Check your windows version it must be greater than or equal to 1903. Or you also enabled "Show accent color on title bars and windows borders" in Settings > Personalization > Colors.

It should be disabled.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I verified that I have a newer Windows. In my case it was really the setting you mentioned in Colors, disabling "Show accent color on the following surfaces -> Title bars and windows borders" did the trick! I wouldn't have looked there, it is not obvious :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a **DarkUI library** available in GitHub, it is described here:

[How to use a DarkUI dark user interface in WinForms C#](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/517/how-to-use-a-darkui-dark-user-interface-in-winforms-c-sharp)

It provides "dark versions" of the common controls too.

For the title bar, try this:
[Change the color of the title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862315/changing-the-color-of-the-title-bar-in-winform)

Maybe it is also a sufficient solution to let the user set up high contrast settings in Windows Personalization (right click the desktop to get there).

Comment: High DPI scale doesn't work in DarkUI library((((((((

Comment: @Andrei Krasutski are you sure? I am using DarkUI and get a high DPI just by calling SetProcessDPIAware();

Comment: @AndreiKrasutski: Do you mean this API function? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiaware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiaware)

Comment: @Matt I mean, this is [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: @AndreiKrasutski - Good to know, thanks, so most of it is to be defined in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers here and from other sources i made a Class "DarkModeCS" to automatically Apply DarkMode Color into all your Controls.

Check it: https://github.com/BlueMystical/Dark-Mode-Forms

No Nuggets, No external DLLs, Just 1 File.