# WinForms Dark title bar on Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

I have a WinForms application which automatically adjusts to the dark/light theme on Windows 10. My problem is that the title bar of my window always stays white, regardless which theme the user selects.

[image]
*Top is current, bottom is how I want it (simulated with Photoshop)*

See `explorer` for example. That is not an UWP app, however it uses a dark title bar on Windows 1903 and newer (when a dark theme is selected).

How can I achieve the same thing? I do not want to use any custom titlebar as I want the application to look and behave like any native application on older Windows versions as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862315/changing-the-color-of-the-title-bar-in-winform

Comment: @User81772 The accepted answer (and all others) do not seem to work on modern versions of Windows

Comment: You will need to hide the top bar and make your own.

Comment: cmd.exe also has a dark titlebar when using the dark theme these days. In the past, I would have expected there to be a window style or API call to make it happen and maintain standard rendering (making the app future-proof when the Windows style changes). With today's MS, I wouldn't be surprised if both File Explorer and cmd.exe use custom hacks instead of them improving the actual OS and APIs for everything. :(

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So after some long searching, I have finally found the answer for this. The trick is to use `dwmapi.dll`'s `DwmSetWindowAttribute` and passing the undocumented constant `DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE` into the function. In C#, the code for this looks a little something like this (works with both WinForms and WPF):

```cs
/*
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
*/

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, ref int attrValue, int attrSize);

private const int DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE_BEFORE_20H1 = 19;
private const int DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE = 20;

private static bool UseImmersiveDarkMode(IntPtr handle, bool enabled)
{
    if (IsWindows10OrGreater(17763))
    {
        var attribute = DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE_BEFORE_20H1;
        if (IsWindows10OrGreater(18985))
        {
            attribute = DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE;
        }

        int useImmersiveDarkMode = enabled ? 1 : 0;
        return DwmSetWindowAttribute(handle, (int)attribute, ref useImmersiveDarkMode, sizeof(int)) == 0;
    }

    return false;
}

private static bool IsWindows10OrGreater(int build = -1)
{
    return Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 10 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build >= build;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I had to additionally hide/show window for this change to take effect.

Comment: Would be nice to know what other call is needed to force change it. But one way to do it without flashing the window or changing focus is to change the window opacity very slightly +/- relative to the current opacity by a small fraction like 0.0000000001 then return it back. This makes the required call that forces it to repaint.

Comment: @PkKingX11 After looking at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,2895b1373643ef53) it seems that a call to SetWindowPos like follows seem to be needed: `SetWindowPos(Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);` Although I have not tried this yet

Comment: Great, it works! Hint: Add `UseImmersiveDarkMode(this.Handle, true);` right after the `InitializeComponent();` call in your form.

Comment: The constant is no longer undocumented since I just opened this PR for it: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/pull/966/files.

Also to force the window to repaint, one can call Invalidate() on the entire form or call SendMessageW with WM_NCPAINT to force an NCPAINT to happen again.

Comment: This works at Windows 11.  Be advised that you will need to include/modify an app.manifest file, at least while Debugging in Visual Studio, to include Windows 10+.

Answer (score 10):

The fastest way:

```
[DllImport("DwmApi")] //System.Runtime.InteropServices
private static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, int[] attrValue, int attrSize);

protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    if (DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, 19, new[] { 1 }, 4) != 0)
        DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, 20, new[] { 1 }, 4);
}
```

Comment: You may want to give a bit more details what those values mean exactly, or better yet use the functions that map literals to object identifiers.

Comment: this just works!! ^_^

Answer (score 3):

For the solution from Jonas Kohl, remember that for .net fw 4.8.1 and prior, the version returned is not ok, fixed in .Net6, here a snippet (.Net 5 is not managed):

```
    private static bool IsWindows10OrGreater(int build = -1)
    {
        return WindowsVersion() >= 10 && WindowsBuildNumber() >= build;
    }

    public static int WindowsVersion()
    {
     //for .Net4.8 and Minor
     #if NETFRAMEWORK
        int result = 10;
        var reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
        string[] productName = reg.GetValue("ProductName").ToString().Split((char)32);
        int.TryParse(productName[1], out result);
        return result;
     #else
        //fixed in .Net6
        return System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major;
     #endif
    }

    public static int WindowsBuildNumber()
    {
        //for .Net4.8 and Minor
    #if NETFRAMEWORK
        int result = 22000;
        var reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
        string buildNumber = reg.GetValue("CurrentBuildNumber").ToString();
        int.TryParse(buildNumber, out result);
        return result;
    #endif

    #if NET
        //fixed in .Net6
        return System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build;
    #endif
    }
```

Comment: If you add an `app.manifest` with the tag `<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />` you will also get back the correct value for `Environment.OSVersion.Version`

Answer (score 0):

Just a note about useage.

I placed the call to use dark mode method in a form's constructor and found that forms inheriting from this form were having problems with StartPosition (possibly the base form, but that's untested).

Changing an inheriting form's StartPosition in the designer to any other value, caused the Location to be used instead (Location was being added to inheriting form's designer code - manually deleting it worked, but it's not a good solution.) Reversing the change does not undo the problem.

Solution is to place the dark mode call in the Load event (tested only on .Net 6)

Comment: The right place for this would be in `OnHandleCreated`