# Changing the color of the title bar c# win 11

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make the color of the title bar blue in my c# form application. I tried the methods on this page: [Changing the color of the title bar in WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862315/changing-the-color-of-the-title-bar-in-winform).

I am using windows 11 and I am preparing the project in .NET Framework 4.7 in visual studio community 2022

Comment: Read the part of the linked question explaining why this is a really bad idea.  Microsoft tends to change how window chrome is rendered from Windows version to Windows version (remember the wavy caption bar in XP or the _glass_ on on Vista).  Also, users expect that they are in charge of decisions like the size, color, contrast and light-vs-darkness of their title bar.  If you do this, your really need to test what it looks like in probably more than a dozen cases (light/dark, different colors, high contrast, various accessibility options, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a NuGet Package called [Guna](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Guna.UI2.WinForms/).

Guna also has their own [website](https://gunaui.com/).

This tutorial shows you how to make a custom Guna form:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5oZnV3cA64&list=WL&index=6

Here is a screenshot I took from the tutorial:

[image]

You can see that there is a custom header in the form.

This method works really well.